# Normalized units for annotations dont add up

Tags: matlab, annotations, matlab-figure

I am creating a color map for data of size(7x24) that I have , lets replace it with some random numbers

```
b = randi(50,7,24);
t = imagesc(b,[min(min(b)) max(max(b))]);
```

now inorder to add annotations I have to know the exact starting and ending point of my axes so that i can add a rectangle to select each point in the image

```
 xPOSITION = get(gca,'Position')

xPOSITION =

    0.1300    0.1100    0.7750    0.8150

annotation('rectangle',[0.13  0.11 (0.7750 - 0.13)/24 (0.8150 -0.11)/7],'FaceColor','blue','FaceAlpha',.2)
```

ok now when i try to add an annotation to the exact starting point of the data , the starting point seem to be fine but the size of the rectangular which should actually be equal to each point is alot smaller 
[image]
according to my calculation each box is equal to (0.7750 - 0.13)/24 X(0.8150 -0.11)/7 , because the units are normalized , am I doing any mistake in calculation ? or the annotation works in a different way ? any help would be highly appreciated

**UPDATE**  just to test I added 0.11 to each dimension of the annotation and it seem to be the exact size for the reason i cannot figure out

```
annotation('rectangle',[0.13  0.11 ((0.7750 - 0.13) +0.11)/24 ((0.8150 -0.11)+0.11)/7],'FaceColor','blue','FaceAlpha',.2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Position` property is the `[left bottom width height]` *not* `[left bottom right top]` as it seems that you're treating it (since you're subtracting element 1 from 3 and 2 from 4). To correctly compute the `rect` for displaying you'll just want to divide the `width` and `height` components by the number of elements in those dimensions.

```
annotation('rectangle', [xPOSITION(1), xPOSITION(2), ...
                         xPOSITION(3)/size(b, 2), xPOSITION(4) / size(b,1)])
```

Or more simply:

```
annotation('rectangle', xPOSITION ./ [1 1 fliplr(size(b))])
```

[image]

That being said, if you're simply wanting to draw rectangles on your data, you're likely better off just creating a [`rectangle`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html) object which is automatically in the units of your data

```
rectangle('Position', [0.5 6.5 1 1], 'LineWidth', 5)
```

Comment: ohh ! I realize my mistake now , thanks for the help it works perfectly now

Comment: Thanks I get it now